# Mysql ensure only one insert for key

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL and spring in my application. I have two services (a,b) calling my service (t). Both services can call with same transactionId. Below are the scenarios I need to handle

1. Service a calls first then b

   Insert a's record in db

   when service b calls modify and update the records inserted by a
2. Service b calls first

   Insert the record directly in db.

   when service a calls, don't do anything.

The problem is when both the service calls at the same time. I need to give preference to service b's call and reject a.

How can I make sure the concurrency the the third case? Should I lock the table?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use transactions (and locks) to control the concurrent access to the tables you have.

Comment: disable auto commits from your Db server and use commit() as you wish.

Comment: @Progman, transaction won't help if both the requests come simultaneously. As per locks, you mean `LOCK tables db_example.mytable  write;` 
Is it a good practice to use locks in Web app ?